# How to display "not found" notification when I set wrong ID from my database MYSQL in <input> with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a case, I create autofill form when I input ID from my database MYSQL, it will appear some data from the table according to the ID that has been inputted. however, when I input the ID are not in the database, the data that appears is the last data I input his ID.

Pic. when I fill ID with "1" from database
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6x1jll5stsd9fy6/1.png?dl=0

Pic. this when I fill ID with "0" mean not found in database
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rlccr9facqlncal/2.png?dl=0
I want when the ID is not found in the database, it will appear "not found" notification.
Can some help me to fix this?

```
    <?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("db_market");
$result = mysql_query("select * from stuff");
$jsArray = "var priceSell = new Array();\n";
$jsArray2 = "var priceBuy = new Array();\n";
?>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Code</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>

    <input name="code" onchange="changeValue(this.value)">
<?php

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
               $jsArray .= "priceSell['" . $row['id'] . "'] = {p1:'" . addslashes($row['price_sell']) . "'};\n";
               $jsArray2 .= "priceBuy['" . $row['id'] . "'] = {p2:'" . addslashes($row['price_buy']) . "'};\n";     
}
?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Price Sell</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="sell" id="sell" value="" disabled></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Price Buy</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="buy" id="buy" value="" disabled></td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php echo $jsArray;echo $jsArray2; ?>
function changeValue(id){
document.getElementById('sell').value = priceSell[id].p1;
document.getElementById('buy').value = priceBuy[id].p2;
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your php with

`if(mysql_num_rows($yourselectquery) > 0){
     //Your Code will be here
 } else {
  echo "Not Found";
 }`

Comment: Better suggest with  `mysqli` it's more better with  `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

According to my opinion, you have to make and use mysqli class to use databases and make your own functions/methods for database queries like a below function which I make and used for my all web applications and dynamic websites.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param String $select Select Columns which data want to fetch or pass * for all columns
 * @param String $from Table name 
 * @param String $where Condition for query or by default is null for all record
 * @param String $orders Sorting Column and limit or by default is null
 * @param Boolean $multipleData True for get multiple record or by default is false for single record
 * @return Array|False Return array if success or False and set error if failed.
 */
function getData($select, $from, $where = null, $orders = null, $multipleData = false) {
    $link = $this->getCon();
    $query = "SELECT " . $select . " FROM " . $from;
    if ($where != null) {
        $query .= " WHERE " . $where;
    }
    if ($orders != null) {
        $query .= " ORDER BY " . $orders;
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if ($result) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $data['result'] = true;
            if ($multipleData) {
                $data['data'] = $this->getMultipleData($result);
            } else {
                $data['data'] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            }
        } else {
            $this->setErrno(mysqli_errno($link));
            $this->setError("Error : Record Not Found");
            $this->setFullError(mysqli_error($link));
        }
    } else {
        $this->setErrno(mysqli_errno($link));
        $this->setError("Error: (" . mysqli_errno($link) . "-DS0x0050131) ");
        $this->setFullError(mysqli_error($link));
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
    return isset($data) && count($data) > 0 ? $data : false;
}
```

Because I like mysqli and maybe is more secure from mysql and you can set your own errors and can modify this function according to your needs.